# How to change HighCharts tooltop to show more details

Tags: highcharts

I need help adjusting the tooltip for the following Highchart example to show "Vacation Used: On Jan 4, 2020. Total is 8 hours used by 2 employees."

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/sha7gwz5/5/

The data looks like this:

```
DATE,MONTH,HOURS,EMPLOYEE COUNT
2020-01-31,01,11,2
2020-02-14,02,14.25,1
2020-02-28,02,7,2
2020-03-13,03,7,1
2020-03-27,03,35.5,3
2020-04-10,04,3,1
2020-04-24,04,3,1
2020-05-08,05,8.75,2
2020-05-22,05,7,2
2020-05-29,05,8,1
2020-06-05,06,7.25,2
2020-06-19,06,83,4
2020-06-30,06,64,2
2020-07-03,07,184,5
2020-07-15,07,48,1
2020-07-17,07,62,5
2020-07-31,07,23.82,2
2020-08-14,08,3,1
2020-08-28,08,11,2
2020-09-11,09,11,2
2020-10-09,10,40,1
2020-12-04,12,16,1
2020-12-18,12,47.25,1
2021-01-04,01,9.5,1
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create data as an array of objects and use additional properties in `tooltip.formatter` function:

```
$.each(data, function(i, point) {
    ...

    chartData.push({
        x,
        y,
        value: val,
        date: row[0],
        hours: parseInt(row[2]),
        count: parseInt(row[3])
    });
});


$(function() {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        tooltip: {
            formatter: function() {
                var point = this.point,
                    date = new Date(point.date);

                return `Vacation Used: On ${Highcharts.dateFormat('%b %e, %Y', date.getTime())}. Total is ${point.hours} hours used by ${point.count} employees.`;
            }
        },
        ...
    });
});
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/k3vwz62j/

**API Reference:**

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.formatter

https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts#.dateFormat

Comment: You nailed it.  That's exactly what I was looking for.  Thank you!